# Can Firebase be used to make a simple forum?

Tags: android, firebase

I want to make a simple forum backend for an Android app for fun. Firebase says that the depth of child nodes cant be greater that 32. So does that mean for example, under the doc-examples node, there can only be 32 nodes (such as android, rest, samplechat, web)?

docs-examples 
 android
 rest
 samplechat
 web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must read more about [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and how you can structure your data.

I have not done any "big" work in firebase but have read some and tried some of the demos. I would say **yes**, you can use it for a forum service. Why will it not work?

The limits are much higher than 32 forum categories ;)

**Limitations and Restrictions in firebase (at the moment):**
[image]

Comment: Doesn't that mean the forum can only have 32 threads at once?

Comment: I means that you can have at most 32 **levels** in the tree. To give you some idea, StackOverflow has only 2 levels: 1=questions/answers, 2=comments.

Comment: @xDr_Johnx 32 nodes are the data structure, depending your solution and your json tree you can manage the universe in one child ;) ... not so fancy solution though..  Read more about json and how you do setup your data model. You will find it very helpful for setup your solution. But for an answer for going with firebase I would definitely use it. I really like the idea and how easy everything is and the mobile friendliness it got with all of caching and concurrency etc.

Comment: @MrSimpleMind So it is a tree of nodes, with a linked list of JSON objects attached to the nodes? Does the linked list have a limit?

Comment: It is a JSON tree, you can't really use linkedlist terms while its a data structure, json is a notation a format. The limits are given in the answer, you have 10mb for erach child as a limit. And as maximum 32 child nodes. This give you hell of space, I doubt you will use this amounts as it will take pretty long time to download your forum posts :) .. you need to think of a scenario, first you donwload the headlines, categories. And then when user enter a category you retrieve the latest posts (I mean you are going for an app, so limitations exist in the display etc). And so on...